# Why won't my prototype execute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, prototype

I want the `Success!` & `Oops!` banner to appear on top of the browser whenever the `goingOutChecker()` prototype works properly & I call the `goingOutChecker()` prototype inside `GeneralChecker()` function.  However, whenever I comment out the `goingOutChecker()` prototype & function call, the `monthlyBillCheckerAndSalaryChecker()` prototype, as well its call, work perfectly.  In other words, both the `Success!` & `Oops!` banner appear as they should whenever the user hits  `Submit` granted the first two fields are filled in correctly or incorrectly.

My question is, why won't `goingOutChecker()` prototype works properly whenever I call the `goingOutChecker()` prototype inside `GeneralChecker()` function?  In other words, whenever all 3 fields are filled in correctly or incorrectly, why won't those banners appear?

Also, I'm getting no errors in the console, just as a side note.

Here's the `gameTime.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WOMP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameTime.css">
</head>     
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="success"></div>
        <div id="danger"></div>
        <div id="success2"></div>
        <div id="danger2"></div>
    </div> 
    <form class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" name="formHandler" id="handle">
        <div id="allFields">
            <div class="moveUsername">
                <h1>(All numbers inputted will be assumed that it's in dollars)</h1>
                <label for="usr">What's your annual salary?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="What's your annual salary?" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="ageMovement">
                <label for="usr">How much do you spend every month on bills?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="monthlyBills" name="ageChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend every month on bills?" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="emailMovement">
                <label for="usr">How much do you spend when going out?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="goingOut" name="emailChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend when going out?" required="required">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default" onsubmit="GeneralChecker()">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gameTime.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the `gameTime.js` file

```
function GeneralChecker(salary, fixedExpense, variableExpense) {
        var self = this;
        self.salary = salary;
        self.fixedExpense = fixedExpense;
        self.variableExpense = variableExpense;
        self.isSalaryZeroOrLess = function() {
            var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);
            console.log(this); 
            if(s <= 0) {
                console.log("Looks like you have no income!");
            } else {
                console.log("Your annual salary is: ", s);
            }
            self.monthlyBillCheckerAndSalaryChecker();
            self.goingOutChecker();
        }
    }

    GeneralChecker.prototype.monthlyBillCheckerAndSalaryChecker = function() {
        var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyBills").value);
        var firstDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var secondDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var node = document.getElementById("danger");
        var node2 = document.getElementById("success");

        if(m <= 0 || isNaN(m)) {
            console.log("Looks like you have no monthly payments to make!");
            secondDiv[2].innerHTML = "<strong>Oops!</strong>  Looks like you have an invalid input.";
            node.className += " alert alert-danger";
        } else {            
            firstDiv[1].innerHTML = "<strong>Success!</strong> Check for advice below.";    
            node2.className += " alert alert-success";
        }

        var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);
        var userMonthlySalary = s / 12;
        console.log(userMonthlySalary);

        if(userMonthlySalary) {
            console.log("That means you make " + userMonthlySalary + " a month.");
        }
    }   

    GeneralChecker.prototype.goingOutChecker = function() {
        var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("goingOut").value);
        var firstDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var secondDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var node = document.getElementById("danger2");
        var node2 = document.getElementById("success2");

        if(m <= 0 || isNaN(m)) {
            console.log("You don't go out much");
            secondDiv[4].innerHTML = "<strong>Oops!</strong>  Looks like you have an invalid input.";
            node.className += " alert alert-danger";
        } else {            
            firstDiv[3].innerHTML = "<strong>Success!</strong> Check for advice below.";    
            node2.className += " alert alert-success";
        }       
    }

    var fin = new GeneralChecker(1000, 1000, 1000);
    document.querySelector("#btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're losing the object context when you bind the event handler. You could do it either like this:

```
document.querySelector("#btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess();
});
```

or like this:

```
document.querySelector("#btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess.bind(fin));
```

The value of `this` depends not on how the function is created with respect to some object, but rather on how the function is *invoked*. By passing the reference to the function as in your original code, the relationship to that `fin` object is lost.

Comment: Hi Pointy.  I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @chompy that's because I typed in a bug :) hold on and I'll fix it. In the first sample, the code needs the `()` to actually call the function.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for your answer btw, it makes a lot of sense :-)

Comment: @chompy well "doesn't work" isn't much to go on. Does *anything* happen? Are there errors in the console? Have you tried adding some `console.log()` calls to see what's going on?

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. Nothing appears in the console whenever I try the second one out of your two suggestions whenever adding a console.log("test") inside `function()`.  It also didn't work when I had `fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess;` in between `function()` as well.

Comment: @chompy well you've got a "submit" button with its "onsubmit" set to call that constructor; that won't do anything useful. You've got the event handler set up properly, it looks like, but the handler doesn't do anything to prevent the `<form>` from being submitted. Thus, once your event handler is finished, the browser will reload the page.

Comment: If you make the button be `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` then the form won't be submitted when the button is clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131918/discussion-between-chompy-and-pointy).